# How to code div/object rotating around another object/div with 3d illusion

Tags: html, css, 3d

I've come to a technical and intellectual impasse. The problem is: I want text to encircle an image and appear like its moving infront of behind the image while the image remains fixed/static.

So far the 1) text that is rotating is nested in side a div=loader. 2) Each letter has its own div so the deg and rotation works and 3) the animation set rotates all the letters so it appears they are encircling. I want the last div within the overall structure to not move at all.

Here's the code

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
}

:root {
  font-size: calc(16px + (24 - 16)*(100vw - 320px)/ (1280 - 320));
}

.preloader {
  display: flex;
}

{
  background: #313030;
  color: #D3E2C0;
  font: 1em Dosis, sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  line-height: 1.5;
  perspective: 40em;
}

.preloader {
  animation: tiltSpin 10s linear infinite;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 17em;
  height: 17em;
}

.preloader,
.preloader__ring {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.preloader__ring {
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 70s;
  animation-timing-function: inherit;
  animation-iteration-count: inherit;
  font-size: 2em;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 1.5rem;
}

.phone_static {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 70%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


}
.preloader__ring:nth-child(even) {
  animation-direction: forward;
}
.second_preloader:nth-child(even) {
  animation-direction: forward;
  animation-duration: 100s;
}
.preloader__sector {
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector,
.preloader__sector:empty:before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.preloader__sector:empty:before {
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 45%, currentColor 45% 55%, transparent 55%);
  content: "";
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateY(12deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotateY(24deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotateY(36deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotateY(48deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(7) {
  transform: rotateY(72deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotateY(84deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(9) {
  transform: rotateY(96deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(10) {
  transform: rotateY(108deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(11) {
  transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(12) {
  transform: rotateY(132deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(13) {
  transform: rotateY(144deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(14) {
  transform: rotateY(156deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(15) {
  transform: rotateY(168deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(16) {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(17) {
  transform: rotateY(192deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(18) {
  transform: rotateY(204deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(19) {
  transform: rotateY(216deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(20) {
  transform: rotateY(228deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(21) {
  transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(22) {
  transform: rotateY(252deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(23) {
  transform: rotateY(264deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(24) {
  transform: rotateY(276deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(25) {
  transform: rotateY(288deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(26) {
  transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(27) {
  transform: rotateY(312deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(28) {
  transform: rotateY(324deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(29) {
  transform: rotateY(336deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(30) {
  transform: rotateY(348deg) translateZ(7rem);
}

/* Animations */
@keyframes tiltSpin {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0) rotateX(30deg);
  }
  
  to {
    transform: rotateY(1turn) rotateX(30deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  
  to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes reversespin {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(deg);
  }
  
  to {
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="preloader">
  <div class="preloader__ring">
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">S</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">E</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">A</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">M</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">L</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">E</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">S</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">S</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="preloader__ring">
    <div class="preloader__sector">U</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">S</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">E</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">R</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">E</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">X</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">P</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">E</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">R</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">I</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">E</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">N</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">C</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">S</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="phone_static">
    <img src="https://github.com/Jitlclarke/ux_portfolio/blob/main/images/small_version_mockup.png?raw=true" alt="" height=560 width=300>
  </div>
</div>
```

What it looks like

1. i've tried putting the  inside a  and affecting the class by using position:fixed and 2) also tried simply creating an animation with deg going the opposite direction with a duration that's quite long but, no luck.

So far i can only get the  or "phone_static" div to rotate in the opposite direction but not stop.

Comment: Are you stuck with that html structure or can you alter it?

Comment: Not opposed to altering it if it gets the job done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phone need to be outside the animated container and you have to add `transform-style: preserve-3d;` to the body element as well. Then all you have to do is to adjust the position of the image.

Here is a non-perfect example that you can easily adjust

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
}

:root {
  font-size: calc(16px + (24 - 16)*(100vw - 320px)/ (1280 - 320));
}

.preloader {
  display: flex;
}

.preloader {
  animation: tiltSpin 10s linear infinite;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 17em;
  height: 17em;
}

body,
.preloader,
.preloader__ring {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.preloader__ring {
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 70s;
  animation-timing-function: inherit;
  animation-iteration-count: inherit;
  font-size: 2em;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 1.5rem;
}

.phone_static {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-39%, -13%);
}
.phone_static img {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
}


}
.preloader__ring:nth-child(even) {
  animation-direction: forward;
}
.second_preloader:nth-child(even) {
  animation-direction: forward;
  animation-duration: 100s;
}
.preloader__sector {
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector,
.preloader__sector:empty:before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.preloader__sector:empty:before {
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 45%, currentColor 45% 55%, transparent 55%);
  content: "";
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateY(12deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotateY(24deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotateY(36deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotateY(48deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(7) {
  transform: rotateY(72deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotateY(84deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(9) {
  transform: rotateY(96deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(10) {
  transform: rotateY(108deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(11) {
  transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(12) {
  transform: rotateY(132deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(13) {
  transform: rotateY(144deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(14) {
  transform: rotateY(156deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(15) {
  transform: rotateY(168deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(16) {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(17) {
  transform: rotateY(192deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(18) {
  transform: rotateY(204deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(19) {
  transform: rotateY(216deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(20) {
  transform: rotateY(228deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(21) {
  transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(22) {
  transform: rotateY(252deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(23) {
  transform: rotateY(264deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(24) {
  transform: rotateY(276deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(25) {
  transform: rotateY(288deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(26) {
  transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(27) {
  transform: rotateY(312deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(28) {
  transform: rotateY(324deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(29) {
  transform: rotateY(336deg) translateZ(7rem);
}
.preloader__sector:nth-child(30) {
  transform: rotateY(348deg) translateZ(7rem);
}

/* Animations */
@keyframes tiltSpin {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0) rotateX(30deg);
  }
  
  to {
    transform: rotateY(1turn) rotateX(30deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  
  to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="preloader">
  <div class="preloader__ring">
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">S</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">E</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">A</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">M</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">L</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">E</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">S</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">S</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="preloader__ring">
    <div class="preloader__sector">U</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">S</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">E</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">R</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">E</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">X</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">P</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">E</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">R</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">I</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">E</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">N</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">C</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector">S</div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
    <div class="preloader__sector"></div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="phone_static">
    <img src="https://github.com/Jitlclarke/ux_portfolio/blob/main/images/small_version_mockup.png?raw=true" alt="" height=560 width=300>
  </div>
```